# Output of Logger and System.out.println are not in order

Tags: java, logging, inputstream, bufferedreader, java.util.logging

I want to have the output of logger and `inputstream` in the eclipse console. But everytime I execute, the result is always not in the same order. I have several classes with one main class to call the others and I put logger to each method for debugging. I print the result to console. I also have the method to retrieve the `inputstream` as `string` and print it into console.

The output example

```
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.Section findSection
INFO: findSection OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.Section convertStringToTestCase
INFO: convertStringToTestCase OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//Error. 
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test1.tc
//Result  : FAILED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:10:58.479
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
Iteration number : 1
mai 19, 2015 4:10:58 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test2.tc
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase setIsPassed
INFO: setIsPassed OK
//Result  : PASSED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:10:58.838
Iteration number : 1
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test3.tc
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase setIsPassed
INFO: setIsPassed OK
//Result  : PASSED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:10:59.229
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
Iteration number : 1
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCaseList verifyList
INFO: verifyList NOK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:10:59 PM ScriptPack.TestCaseList verifyList
INFO: verifyList NOK
//Error. 
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test1.tc
//Result  : FAILED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:10:59.635
Iteration number : 2
```

Then I re-execute and get different order

```
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.Section findSection
INFO: findSection OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.Section convertStringToTestCase
INFO: convertStringToTestCase OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//Error. 
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test1.tc
//Result  : FAILED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:13:24.321
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
Iteration number : 1
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:24 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test2.tc
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase setIsPassed
INFO: setIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
//Result  : PASSED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:13:24.789
Iteration number : 1
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test3.tc
//Result  : PASSED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:13:25.228
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase setIsPassed
INFO: setIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
Iteration number : 1
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCaseList verifyList
INFO: verifyList NOK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getName
INFO: getName OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase settIterationNumber
INFO: settIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIterationNumber
INFO: getIterationNumber OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCase getIsPassed
INFO: getIsPassed OK
//Error. 
//**********EasyTest Test Report**********
//Test Case: testCase/test1.tc
//Result  : FAILED
//Start at: 2015-05-19-T16:13:25.587
Iteration number : 2
mai 19, 2015 4:13:25 PM ScriptPack.TestCaseList verifyList
INFO: verifyList NOK
```

The line starts with double slash comes from `inputstream` and should be assembled. I tried to put synchronized in each method but doesn't work. If I put `Thread.sleep()`, where should I put it? Is there any more safety way to synchronize the output?

Comment: How is your logging set up. Is it printing to `stdout` or `stderr`? Same question about lines printed outside of logging API? If they differ, the difference in output may be because `stdout` is buffered and `stderr` is not.

Comment: I use same logger in each class :  private static Logger theLogger = Logger.getLogger("File1"). Then put theLogger.info(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString() + " OK") in ieach method. Besides logging, I use System.out.println() to print into console.  I used System.err.println to print inputstream and still have the same problem

Comment: A logger usually prints to `stderr` if not specifically configured to do otherwise. Have you set up any specific logging configuration? If not, and you don't know how, it may be easier to change `System.out.println` to `System.err.println` to see if your problem disappears.

Comment: System.err.println works perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 3):

*The issue has been resolved through a discussion in the comments to the question. I'm posting this information as an answer in case someone else has the same problem and finds this question when searching.*

---

Logger API's usually outputs logging to `stderr` if no specific configuration has been done. Calls to `System.out.println()` will of course go to `stdout`.

The problem with output to a console differing at each run of a program, when intermixing both methods, is due to the fact that `stdout` is usually buffered, while `stderr` is not. To fix this kind of problem, one has to make sure that both methods prints to the same type of outputstream, both to `stdout` or both to `stderr`.

To find out how to do this for the logger API, you have to look in the documentation for the logger. For `System.out.println()` (and the other print methods) you will have to switch to `System.err` instead, i.e. `System.err.println()`, or vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

instead of sleep, you can use wait if you know the amount of time you want each thread to wait.
Or use one thread to lock and open the other... it all depends on your needs.
When using multi thread the result will never be exactly the same unless they are NOT working simultaneously.
If the order is impotent you have some changes that need to be done.
Try using one of the thread pool family objects.
Here a tutorial that might help
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I call the methods in the order so they should execute in sequence either, shouldn't they? As multithread executes in the same time, I dont understand your point about multithread in my case