# Java - Problem with the logger on console

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm developing the Connect4 game in Java and i'm having problem with the Logger. I don't know why prints in different place ad between other kind of prints.

```
public void setPlacement(Move lastMove){
    Logger.getGlobal().info("Player" + lastMove.getPlayerIndex() + " placed a checker in position : " + lastMove.toString());
    display();
}
```

The method display() just prints the grid of the game. Here's the output of the above method :

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - ago 01, 2019 6:10:24 PM it.unicam.cs.pa.connectFour.GameViewsetPlacement
INFO: Player1 placed a checker in position : column 4, row 5
| - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | O | O | O | - | - | - |
| O | X | X | X | - | - | - |

*****************************
```

Can someone explain me why the logger acts like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329258/output-of-logger-and-system-out-println-are-not-in-order) concerning System::out and System::err may help you. Specifically, your console is displaying two streams of output at the same time, with no ordering guarantees between messages sent to different streams.

One way to enable Loggers to write to a standard output stream is to create your own [StreamHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html#StreamHandler-java.io.OutputStream-java.util.logging.Formatter-) and configure your Logger to send input to the handler instead. You may also have to [disable parent handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers(boolean)) to avoid duplicate output. You may also want to ensure that output is proactively sent to the desired output stream, as so:

```
Handler h = new StreamHandler(System.out, formatter)
    {
        public void publish(LogRecord record)
        {
            if(record == null)
                return;
            super.publish(record);
            super.flush();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Since the question mentioned Eclipse I want to add that the next release (4.13) plan to add an option to guarantee the Console output order. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/jdt.php#console-output-synchronization